# Create Private CocoaPod that uses other Pod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, cocoapods-1.0.1

I am trying to create a private CocoaPod that I will use/install in another project lets call my pod "MyPod" and my project "MyProject".
MyPod is depending on another pod called BMSSecurity. Here you can see the Podfile for MyPod:

```
target 'MyPod' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'BMSSecurity'
end
```

MyPod can be built just fine and BMSSecurity is imported
I am following the guides to create a private pod but when I install MyPod in MyProject with pod install everything looks fine except that the pod BMSSecurity in MyPod is not installed so MyProject won't build.
MyProject can't find the files needed from BMSSecurity
Here is the Podfile for MyProject:

```
target 'MyProject' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'MyPod', :path => '../MyPod'
end
```

../MyPod is the location where the specfile for MyPod is located

How can i get Cocoapods to understand that it need to install the pods in the pod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add BMSSecurity as a dependency of your private pod.  In your .podspec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name             = 'MyPod'
    s.version          = '1.0.0'
    s.summary          = 'A short description of MyPod.'

    # ...

    s.dependency 'BMSSecurity'

    # ...

end
```

Comment: IT WORKS MATE, thx soo much. You dont understand how much this means to me, saved my weekend : )